# Creating a trial app with a feature that expires after being used twice

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to add a feature to my app that user can avail only twice or thrice in the trial mode. I am unable to figure out which purchase mode should I implement.

I successfully implemented the in-app-purchase for making the feature available for lifetime. But how should I go about limiting it if the user has not bought it?

I am following this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Licensing-API-Sample-19712f1a) and according to it I have following options:

Expiring Product: This allows me to expire the feature after certain period of time.

InAppPurchase: I can purchase feature through this but I cannot limit the feature in trial mode.

ConsumableInAppPurchase: Again it requires the user to buy the feature first and then it can be consumed.

I figured that if I can save an int in local settings of app the first time app is used and then decrement it until its 0, and then prompt the user to buy it it will do the job. But if I use this method user can always delete the settings file and my app wouldn't know that it is not being used the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just store the number of times your feature has been used in the app's roaming settings and then block it unless it's been purchased if you detect the app is running in trial mode?

Comment: wouldn't it create the same issue as saving in local settings? User can delete roaming settings file too

Comment: So what? They'll need to do it every time they want to use your feature. Do you think people will want to hack it so much to save a dollar or two?

Comment: I just don't think this is a good enough reason not to look for a more secure option.. But I guess there is no other option after all! Thanks